# Is it possible to destroy Dagger 2 graph or clear all memory allocated by it?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I build my AppComponent with method like that:

```
public void buildObjectGraph() {
        component = DaggerMyAppComponent.builder()
                .myAppModule(new myAppModule(this))
                .apiModule(new ApiModule())
                .dataModule(new DataModule())
                .utilsModule(new UtilsModule())
                .backendModule(new BackendModule())
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
}
```

If I invoke method for the 2nd time it will create another graph with new objects (singletons) instances but previously created graph exists until garbage collected by system. Depending on what kind of objects were created inside of it - it can take time because there might be some async operations, api calls and other stuff that is not needed anymore but still need to finish.

I know it sounds ridiculous to build many graphs but I am using it in testing only.

What I am looking for is to somehow destroy all objects created after 1st invoke of buildObjectGraph(). I can have reference to AppComponent with them.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly destroy objects in Java. You can hint the garbage collector to garbage collect(System.gc()), but it is not guaranteed at all.